# Wrong dataframe structure using Panda

Tags: python

I'm trying to a data frame, currently I'm take the value from an already existing data frame.
The row 'data, looks like this:

01 03 55 55 55 55 55 55

and i would like to split each of these values up;

but the d1 is getting 3 instead of 1, like shown in the attached picture.

[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8d49.png)

The row['data'] is the value in this data frame seen in the picture;

[data frame include row 'data'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8nN4.png)

```
data = StringIO(row['data'])
df_data = pd.read_csv(data, delimiter=' ', names=['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6',
                                                                         'd7', 'd8'])
```

I have tried using read_table too, but with the same outcome

Comment: `01 03 55 55 55 55 55 55` Is this row from a `csv`?

Comment: it's from a dataFrame that is structure by using read_table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
z = StringIO("""01 03 55 55 55 55 55 55""")
df = pd.read_table(z, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', ' d8'])

print(df)
   d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  d6  d7  d8
0   1   3  55  55  55  55  55  55
```

Comment: But I would like not to hardcode it because the data can change.

Comment: Just replace the way you read the data. The things that you have to be careful with are whether the `header` is included in the data or not, which is the `col_index` and the `delimeter`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `.csv` file, you can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=' ', names=['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd8'], index_col=False)
```